Strftime not declared PlatformIO, ESP32
strftime has stopped working in my platformIO project. It was running fine this morning and i don't see what i've changed that could cause this.
The error i'm getting is identifier "strftime" is undefined. The time.h file where this should be pulled out of now looks like this:
#ifndef _ESP_TIME_H
#define _ESP_TIME_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include_next <time.h>

#define _POSIX_TIMERS 1
#ifndef CLOCK_MONOTONIC
#define CLOCK_MONOTONIC (clockid_t)4
#endif
#ifndef CLOCK_BOOTTIME
#define CLOCK_BOOTTIME (clockid_t)4
#endif

int clock_settime(clockid_t clock_id, const struct timespec *tp);
int clock_gettime(clockid_t clock_id, struct timespec *tp);
int clock_getres(clockid_t clock_id, struct timespec *res);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* _ESP_TIME_H */

This suggests the platformIO building tool is trying to build with the esp-idf framework instead of the arduino framework i have configured in platformIO.ini.
Any input would be greatly appreciated, i'm at a loss...
I have tried deleting the .pio folder in my project, the framework folder in platformIO's packages folder and i have tried the clean and full clean commands.

If it is working in the morning and not working in the evening, it is likely have to do with your code and maybe the platformio configuration. Certainly nothing to do with some function prototypes definition of some built-in library. Do you have #include <time.h> in your code?

Yes, #include <time.h> is in my code, i have also tried <sys/time.h>, which did not resolve the issue

Is the above code the file "time.h" in your project? In this case, #include_next <time.h> will include itself and not the standard time.h. Generally, using include_next is a very bad idea, especially in new code. There might be a reason in legacy code but really, it seldom is a good reason.

Yes, that is the time.h in my project, i don't know why it is this file, i did not write it myself. I read something about include_next being a bad idea, but i do not know where this file even came from.

So you just have to replace #include_next <time.h> by #include <time.h> to fix the issue.

I had already tried that, and it didn't work. It kept including itself.

I found a workaround where i can use strftime_l() and just call it with localisation argument NULL.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
